# React - Is there a memory tradeoff for functions outside of components

Tags: reactjs, performance, memory

So it seems that it is a best practice to define functions that don't need to be inside a component outside of that component to prevent it from being recreated on each render.
Is there any drawback to doing that in terms of memory? If so, how should that be evaluated?

It seems that most people start out defining everything inside of a component and hopefully realize soon enough that this can come along with significant drawbacks. But what are the cases where the function (or any variable for that matter) actually **should** be defined inside of the component?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Stick to one question, and be specific. Ideally with code examples to go along with it. Otherwise questions tend to be open for interpretation and the quality of both question and answers suffer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that defining function either inside or outside doesn't matter at all because re-rendering is something which React JS/ React native handled way more perfectly. https://reactnative.dev/architecture/threading-model given link and other blogs either on Medium or similar website can make you clear about that.